# Pandas: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid continuation byte

Tags: pandas, csv, unicode, utf-8, codec

community. I want to open a CSV using pandas and perform analysis on it. Please, help as I am not able to open the CSV itself. I tried opening it with UTF-8, Latin-1, and ISO-8859-1 encoding. It didn't work. 
CODE:

```
csv_file3='COVID-19-geographic-disbtribution-worldwide.csv'
with open(csv_file3,'rt')as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    j=0
    for row in data:
         j+=1
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analysisofcases.py", line 87, in <module>
    for row in data:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte
```

[This is the CSV that I want to open.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pydeA.png) 
[This is my code and the error when I ran the code.** Please check and see what the problem is**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRRxr.png)

Answer (score 35):

Try this,check this [standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) as well.

```
data = pd.read_csv("COVID-19-geographic-disbtribution-worldwide.csv", encoding = 'unicode_escape', engine ='python')
```