# Pandas Encoding

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apache-nifi

I am executing python code with APache Nifi ExectureStreamCommand

I read a csv which I know the encoding is latin. So I am reading my file (file stream object) with :

```py
pd.read_csv(sys.stdin, encoding='latin')
```

But pandas keep throwing to me this error:

```py
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 172: invalid continuation byte
```

Thus it seems that pandas do not look at all at the given encoding parameter, and try utf-8 at any cost !

Any idea ? Thank you for you help

Comment: These posts could be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18171739/11246056 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/61267213/11246056

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly managed to find a solution.

I guess pandas try to open the file stream, and than consider it as a csv and apply the encoding. By default it open the file stream (sys.stdin) with utf-8.
Thus I transformed sys.stdin with the following; which encode the file stream with the good encoding:

```py
sys.stdin= io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='latin')
```